# phpexcel Append lines into one cell in a while loop

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an Query who gives me an output of 4 recordsets like:

```
    |1  |Tree       |
    |2  |Apple      |
    |3  |Orange     |
    |4  |Strawberry |
```

In my PHP file i get these output correctly.
Now i want to get all these 4 recordsets after an Export in one Excel Cell like in A8, but there i get only the last recordset

```
    |4  |Strawberry |
```

i don't know why it doesn't works. Here my code:

```
    $MRabfrage = "SELECT motif_regularisation 
                        FROM regul_stock_devise
                        WHERE regul_stock_devise.date_regularisation = '$dreg'";

    $MRergebnis = mysql_query($MRabfrage) or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());

    while($rowM = mysql_fetch_array($MRergebnis))
        {
            $motif        =   $rowM['motif_regularisation'];

            $objWorksheet->setCellValue('A8', $motif."\n");
            $objWorksheet->getStyle('A8')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
            $rowM++;
        }
```

What is to do to resolve these problem?

THX in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to get this?

```
+--------+-----------+
|4       |Tree       |
|        |Apple      |
|        |Orange     |
|        |Strawberry |
+--------+-----------+
```

You need to append value, not overwrite it, in each iteration:

```
$prev_value = $objWorksheet->getCell('A8')->getValue();
$objWorksheet->setCellValue('A8', $prev_value.$motif."\n");
```